# Is it possible to use both bounding boxes and block containers in Google Cloud Vision OCR?

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

My goal is to use google cloud vision to identify handwritten paragraphs adn their bounding boxes.

I am trying to use the feature from Google's cloud vision "Document Text Detection" API where you can find handwritten text split into blocks, paragraphs, words, and symbols. This is very doable.
[Here is a link to the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/handwriting)

Likewise, I can use Google's "Text Detection" API to locate coordinates for a bounding box.
[Here is a link to the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr)

My problem is these two branches are not compatible, and i cannot run both at once (i am looking to find a bounding box around a paragraph).

** Does anyone know how to do bounding boxes with "Document Text Detection" or block containers on "Text Detection" for Google Cloud Vision?**

However, I can't seem to manage to use these two features simultaneously (using python FYI).

Cheers. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't if I understood correctly your doubt - please correct me if I got it wrong.

If I understand, you want to have the handwritten text detected together with bounding boxes identifying the text location into the image.

To do it, as you can quickly test on the [Try It](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/handwriting#try_it) session on the Vision AI documentation, you simply need to handle the API response. You will get a response part like this:

```
"textAnnotations": [
        {
          "locale": "en",
          "description": "Google Claud\nPlatform",
          "boundingPoly": {
            "vertices": [
              {
                "x": 296,
                "y": 68
              },
              {
                "x": 712,
                "y": 68
              },
              {
                "x": 712,
                "y": 253
              },
              {
                "x": 296,
                "y": 253
              }
            ]
          }
        }
```

And checking the [Python SDK documentation for Vision AI](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/vision/latest/google.cloud.vision_v1.types.BoundingPoly), those x's and y's build the polygon identifying where the text relies in.